# Normalize a set of numbers (remove nulls, consecutive duplicates, shift remaining values to the left)

Tags: sql-server, function, normalization

I have a data row with 5 numeric columns.
I want to:

```
Remove Zero/NULL values
Remove consecutive duplicates
```

After removal of Nulls / Duplicates, I want to shift the remaining values to the left - I do not want to sort the values.

I'm assuming that the first parameter is always a non Zero/Null.

The output would have NULLs in place of any of the elements that were removed. Since remaining values shift to the LEFT, NULLs only exist on the RIGHT end of the output.

Here are some example:

```
10,20,30,40,50 = 10,20,30,40,50
50,20,30,40,50 = 50,20,30,40,50
10,10,20,30,50 = 10,20,30,50,NULL
10,10,20,10,50 = 10,20,10,50,NULL
10,10,00,10,50 = 10,50,NULL,NULL,NULL
10,10,10,10,10 = 10,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
10,00,10,00,10 = 10,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
```

I was building a solution within a Stored Procedure using a CTE, but eventually decided to try writing a function.

The function works but is poorly written. Also, I'm not sure how to incorporate the function into my stored procedure, where a generic SELECT pulls in the data, then feeds it to a function, and the function (currently returning a table) should behave (I think) like two tables being JOINED.

My function is below.

I'll appreciate you input with regards to my overall approach, and if it's sound, your improvements to my function. Wiring the FUNCTION into a SELECT statement, I am also looking for.

Thank you.

```
create function ColumnShifter (@1 decimal,@2 decimal,@3 decimal,@4 decimal,@5 decimal)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN

WITH ROUND1 AS(
  Select
   @1  [1]
  ,coalesce(@2,@3,@4,@5) [2]
  ,coalesce(@3,@4,@5) [3]
  ,coalesce(@4,@5) [4]
  ,@5 [5])
,ROUND2 AS (
  Select
   [1]
  ,NULLIF([2],[1]) [2]
  ,NULLIF([3],[2]) [3]
  ,NULLIF([4],[3]) [4]
  ,NULLIF([5],[4]) [5]
  from
   Round1   )
,ROUND3 AS (
  Select
   [1]
  ,coalesce([2],[3],[4],[5]) [2]
  ,coalesce([3],[4],[5]) [3]
  ,coalesce([4],[5]) [4]
  from
   Round2   )
,ROUND4 AS (
  Select
   [1]
  ,NULLIF([2],[1]) [2]
  ,NULLIF([3],[2]) [3]
  ,NULLIF([4],[3]) [4]
  from
   Round3   )
,ROUND5 AS (
  Select
   [1]
  ,coalesce([2],[3],[4]) [2]
  ,coalesce([3],[4]) [3]
  ,[4]
  from
   Round4   )
,ROUND6 AS (
  Select
   [1]
  ,NULLIF([2],[1]) [2]
  ,NULLIF([3],[2]) [3]
  ,NULLIF([4],[3]) [4]
  from
   Round5   )
select * from ROUND6
GO
Select * from ColumnShifter(10,10,20,20,100)
```

Comment: By `10,10,10,10,10 = 10` do you mean `10,10,10,10,10` should be displayed as `10,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL`?

Comment: Yes - however I felt that excluding the NULLS would make the example output clearer. For example, I didn't include NULL data in my source examples. I'll note your observations in the question.

Comment: *"however I felt that excluding the NULLS would make the example output clearer. "* not it makes it less clear. You saying that means I don't know now if `10,10,00,10,50` should be `10, NULL, 50, NULL, NULL`, or `10, 50, NULL, NULL, NULL` now. Your expected results should reflect your needs. Otherwise it looks like you want a return dataset with *less* columns for some rows; which is impossible (as it isn't allowed)

Comment: I'll update the question per your concerns.